# sudo apt-get purge aws | Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package aws

Tags: ubuntu, aws

[image: Informacion del error.]

Quiero eliminar el paquete de aws para volver a instalar desde cero una versión más reciente a la fecha porque así lo requiero para `localstack`, pero el comando `$ sudo apt-get purge aws` no funciona genera el error:

```
nebulosa@LAPTOP-LA9SFT99:~$ sudo apt-get purge aws

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package aws.
```

Answer (score 0):

El paquete no se llama `aws`, la propia salida de `aws --version` te da una pista:

> **aws-cli**/1.32.4 Python...

El paquete que quieres instalar se llama en Ubuntu [awscli](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/awscli), por lo tanto, si originalmente fue instalado mediante el gestor de paquetes (y no manualmente, o mediante pip, etc) deberías poder desinstalarlo y eliminar los archivos de configuración con:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge awscli
```

Comment: Hola tu comando me funciono pero es raro porque cuando aplico nuevamente **aws --version** genera la std-out con la version del screenshot que envie en mi pregunta...